# Get generic data with nhibernate

Tags: c#, generics, nhibernate, get

I wanna create universal/generic method for getting data from various entities.
This is my code...

```
public T GetOldData<T>(ISession session, object id) where T : class
{
     var data = session.Get<T>(id);

     return data;
}
```

...but I allways got this error:

> Ambiguous persister for System.Object implemented by more than one
>   hierarchy.

I call it with: `var data = GetOldData<object>(session, @event.Entity);`

Answer (score 1):

When you pass the `object` to your `Get<>` generic method, NHibernate does not know what mapped entity you need. What you have to do is to provide what entity you need, for sample:

```
var data = GetOldData<Customer>(session, customerId);
```

You also could implement a method to provide a type instead of a generic. For sample:

```
var entityType = typeof(Customer); // or something dynamic

var data = (Customer) GetOldData(session, entityType, id);
```

And implement the method:

```
public object GetOldData(ISession session, Type entityType, object id) 
{
     var data = session.Get(entityType, id);

     return data;
}
```